# Unable to create process using templmets

Tags: processmaker, processmaker-api

I am using

processmaker 4.6.2
Apache/2.4.56 (Win64)
PHP/8.1.17
mySQL 8.1.17
While trying to create a new process using existing templates I am getting the following error from URL:
http://localhost/api/1.0/template/create/process/1

```
message": "Can not import because Package Comments is not installed.",
"exception": "ProcessMaker\\Exception\\PackageNotInstalledException",
"file": "E:\\BpM\\xampp1\\processmaker\\ProcessMaker\\ImportExport\\Manifest.php",
"line": 111,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "E:\\BpM\\xampp1\\processmaker\\ProcessMaker\\ImportExport\\Manifest.php",
        "line": 87,
        "function": "checkClass",
        "class": "ProcessMaker\\ImportExport\\Manifest",
        "type": "::"
    }
```

Same error I am getting if i am trying to edit existing template

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the comment package provided in the enterprise version of Processmaker.
https://processmaker.gitbook.io/processmaker-release-notes/processmaker-platform-release-notes/non-core-package-versions

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34896078)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).